# Where is the "Posts"/"Blog" template?

Tags: posts, blog

I want to modify the "Posts" template. But I can't find it's location, I believe it's unrelated to my theme. Where is it located? Could I copy it and create an identical template in my theme so as to not mess around with the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Posts** (note the plural) template does not exists.

The archive of standard post type, when is not a more *specific* template (date archive, author archive, taxonomy archive) is handled by:

`home.php` (and if this file doesn't exist) by `index.php`.

If you intend **Post** (note the singular) the right template file is `single.php`

Once understood this, to modify the template follow @JMau [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110871/where-is-the-posts-blog-template/110872#110872): create a child theme.

## Edit

the informations above are not a *secret*, but are fully accessible in the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) page of Codex as @hereswhatidid says in the comment below.

Comment: Also, I would highly recommend reading through the Template Hierarchy page on WordPress.org:http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: +1 from me, I forgot to add the link in my original answer. @hereswhatidid

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify a file called [single.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). You could set up a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to not mess with the original theme.

This technique is the safest and easiest way to modify an existing theme. Basically you create a theme that inherits from the parent theme. It's good for maintenance when themes (parent theme here) are often updated.